# How to limit the power of the brushless motor

Tags: brushless-motors, aircraft, power

I need to limit the power of my brushless motor at 700 Watts. How I can do it?

I dont have a fix motor or propeller, for any configuration the max consumed power need to be less or equal 700W.

The max current is ~50A, but the voltage can be changed.

I looked for commercial power limiters but I didn't find any that would meet the high current with the adjustable power value.

The project is a aircraft model and I can use and/or development hardware and softwares periferics.

Answer (score 4):

Hi mate the design of an ESC with a power limiter is not an easy task.

[image]

A purchased ESC will probably have a means of limiting torque or current, but not power. Battery current is probably the best indication of total power delivered by the battery. However a given current level will result in less power as the battery voltage declines. Total battery power is power used by the propellor plus motor losses plus ESC losses.

**Answer 1:** The pragmatic approach:
You could test a motor-ESC-propellor combination at various speeds then limit the speed to whatever results in 700 W use, you may find various simulators online, like this one: https://rcplanes.online/calc_motor.htm .

[image: ![enter image description here]

See the simulation for a 700 W max system above.

**Answer 2:** The electronic engeneering approach:
since the instantaneous electrical power is given by the instant voltage*the instant current, we should measure both and limit the output using a custom designed limiter: The result of the battery power estimate or calculation could be used to reduce the speed command when the power exceeds a set limit (in our case 700 W). The system would essentially prevent the propellor speed from exceeding the speed that results in the set power limit whatever that speed happens to be under the prevailing conditions.
Moreover there is a similar discussion here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594444/how-to-do-a-power-limiter-for-brushless-motor
Happy to go in more depth if you may need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by choosing the correct battery and propeller combination--that's it. Choose a battery. Fully charge it. Then, start testing propellers with a power meter in series with your battery. Continually reduce the diameter or pitch or both of the propeller until the power is below 700W at full throttle. Done.